# Seeking help with a Limit with an Exponential numerator

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to take the following limit
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}\exp{\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{2} \left(\sqrt{\pi }-1\right) t^B e^{-\frac{t^{2 B}}{2 \sqrt{2}}}}{\pi }-\frac{\left(2 \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{\pi }-1\right) t^{2 B}+\sqrt{\pi }+2\right) \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{t^B}{2^{3/4}}\right)}{4 \sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{1}{2}\right)},
$$
where 
$\operatorname{erfc} \left(z\right)$ is the complementary error function given by
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{erfc}(z) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_z^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-t^2} \,dt 
\end{equation}
and $0 \le B \le 1$.
I have tried using Lhospital's rule but the numerator started to unwind and I was not sure how to proceed after the first derivative.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponent goes to a constant ($\frac12$ unless $B=0$), so the limit is zero. You can't apply L'Hôpital's rule because the numerator doesn't go to $0$.